# Analysis Services Only Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, ssas, analysis

Is it true that Analysis Services ONLY supports windows authentication?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it does. Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143708.aspx)

*"SQL Server Analysis Services supports only Windows Authentication"*

You'll need active directory, Refer to the following kb on how to set it up
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917409

Answer (score 10):

Actually needing "Active Directory" isn't really true.

You can trick OS's by logging into your PC in any domain with the same User and Password as the account on the other server that's running SSAS.   I do it all the time.  By default you'll get access if the domains are different but the user/pass is exact.

Answer (score 4):

Dependent on what you're trying to achieve, you can connect via HTTP and IIS, with IIS supplying or passing through credentials:

http://www.sqlserveranalysisservices.com/OLAPPapers/ConfiguringHTTPAccessToYukon.htm

Comment: This is a good reference for setting up HTTP access to analysis services.
http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/mglaser/archive/2008/08/15/configuring-http-access-to-sql-server-2008-analysis-services-on-microsoft-windows-server-2008.aspx

Comment: SQLServerAnalysisServices.com does not host the above content anymore

Comment: There's an archive here: https://web.archive.org/web/20200218121243/http://mglaser.bloggingabout.net/2008/08/15/configuring-http-access-to-sql-server-2008-analysis-services-on-microsoft-windows-server-2008/

Answer (score 1):

Needing AD is certainly not true. You can use a tool like `runas` to execute a program under a different user account.

For example in my dev enviroment I sometimes use it to run Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS) or Visual Studio under a different user.

SSMS:

```
runas /netonly /user:domain\username "C:\path_to\Ssms.exe"
runas /netonly /user:domain\username "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"
```

Visual Studio:

```
runas /netonly /user:domain\username "C:\path_to\devenv.exe"
runas /netonly /user:domain\username "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

The `runas` tool will prompt you for the password and starts the program under that user.

If there is no domain, you can use the name of the computer.