# Dimensional Level Security / Per User Data Security in SSAS Cube?

Tags: analytics, ssas, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, cube

I'm part of a team looking to move from our relational data warehouse to a SSAS cube.  With our current setup we have an "EmployeeCache" table (basically a fact) which is a mapping from each of our employee ids to their viewable employee ids.  This table is joined in our model to our DimEmployee table so that for every query that needs personally identifiable information the DimEmployee records are filtered.  The filter is applied from a session variable that is the user id which is making the query.

All of the examples we researched to provide dimension level security in a SSAS cube have required the use of Windows managed security.  The systems that create the data that is being analyzed handle their own security.  Our ETLs map the security structure into the aforementioned EmployeeCache and DimEmployee tables.  We would like to keep this simple structure of security.

As we see it there is no way to pass in session values (aside from using the query string which we're not seeing it possible with Cognos 10.1) to the cube.  We're also not seeing any examples out there on security which does not require the use of Windows auth.

Can someone explain if there is a way to achieve dimensional security as I have previously described in a SSAS cube?  If there is no way possible could another cube provider have this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts. Firstly, SSAS only supports windows authentication (see [Analysis Services Only Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626078/analysis-services-only-windows-authentication)) and this is unchanged in Sql Server 2012. But you can pass credentials in the connection string to analysis services. Secondly, could you alter the MDX of every query and add a slicer to restrict the data to only the data a user should see?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm no longer in the research phase of this project and we tabled it since we couldn't figure out how to take the current user which was logged in and pass that into the MDX query that was generated by Cognos.  If we were generating these queries it may be easier, but with a 3rd party tool doing it we don't have level of control.  I appreciate the answer though.